# Jmeter extract values from response with nested values as null

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am using Json Path Extractor to extract root reponse:
which looks like:

```
[a,b,c] 
[a,c] [b,c]
```

So i want extractor to get values using $ as expression, so it will be put into variable like this:

```
[a,b,c] [a,null,c],[null,b,c]
```

But when I do as I say I get only empty value for resulting variable.

Is there simple solution for what I want to achieve?

I use Jmeter 3.2 and jpgc Standard Set tools in version: 2.0

Comment: Can you share your test plan what you did?

Comment: This is the test for our company API service. So even if I share my test plan, you cannot run it.

Comment: I just want to see the response example and how to parsing it, can be with dummy sampler ,to understand your issue

Comment: I just get list of items and then use JsonPath extractor with $ in JsonPath Expression